# What really do ObjectSpace._id2ref method return?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3

I have an example:

```
def a
   puts "Hello"
end
r = ObjectSpace._id2ref(a.object_id) # r is a reference to a
r == a #=> true
r #=> nil
```

Why then it is impossible to call `a` with `r`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get method references by name like that. `a` is nil in your example when you pass it to `#_id2ref`, because Ruby is trying to find a local variable named `a`.

```
a.class => nil
r.class => nil
```

Thus, `r == a` because both `r` and `a` are nil.

However, you can get a reference to `#a` with `#method`:

```
> r = ObjectSpace._id2ref(method(:a).object_id)
 => #<Method: Object#a>
> r == method(:a)
 => true
> r.call
Hello
 => nil
```

Comment: It’s not that Ruby is trying and failing to find a local variable named `a`, rather the method `a` is called, which returns `nil` (since `puts` returns `nil`).